# How to capture Windows msg.exe (previously net send) message through Java?

Tags: java, windows, capture, msg

As you might already know, Msg.exe replaced "Net Send" on the later Windows versions, but they basically do the same thing.  Is there a way to listen and capture these messages (which are in a Windows alert box)?.

My main goal is to log them to a text file and maybe create a better looking GUI for it.